# for loop in mysql id dictionary with values

Tags: python, mysql, loops, for-loop

My goal is to come up with the average of points

Im using a for loop to do a mysql query in python. This query returns the following id's along with some values:

```
    {'speed_range_id': 0, 'count(speed_range_id)': 511}
{'speed_range_id': 1, 'count(speed_range_id)': 1827}
{'speed_range_id': 2, 'count(speed_range_id)': 48}
{'speed_range_id': 4, 'count(speed_range_id)': 100}
{'speed_range_id': 8, 'count(speed_range_id)': 60}
```

What i want to do is to create a dictionary that maps the id to a value, say `speed_range_id:1 = 15km/hr, speed_range_id:2 = 25 km, speed_range_id:4 = 50 km/hr` and so on.

I would like to then multiply the `count(speed_range_id)': 1827` times the value i gave the id, in this case `1827*15` and so on for every other id. I'd then have to add up the result of every ID and divide it by the total sum of the counts `1827+48+100+60=2035` in order to come up with the average km/hr

I am stuck trying to create the dictionary of values for the speed_range_id's and store them in a variable. I think it's necesasary i do some if statements?

Any help or guidance is appreciated. 
My for loop currently looks like this:

```
for rowdict in result:
    cursor2.execute(speed_query, rowdict)
    speed_result = cursor2.fetchall()
    for rowdict2 in speed_result:
        print(rowdict2)
```

Comment: Well, how do you get the values to map `speed_range_id` to

Comment: @swhat i'd declare them. for this example i would do 
1 = 0, 2 = 25, 9 = 50, 10 = 75, 11 = 100, 12 = 150 and 13 = 15. 
I guess since 1 equals to i'd have to exclude that id

Comment: So you'd have another dict, from your example `{1:15, 2:25, 4:50}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a dict `id_vals` to store the associations of id and values, and also `speed_result` as you have in your loop already. You can use `sum` with a generator expression to evaluate the sum of something for each element in `speed_result`.

```
id_vals = {1:15, 2:25, 4:50...}
result_sum = sum(id_vals[row['speed_range_id']]*row['count(speed_range_id)'] for row in speed_result)
count_sum = sum(row['count(speed_range_id)'] for row in speed_result)
avg = result_sum/count_sum
```

Comment: The dictionary approach is what i'm looking for, however, when i run the result_sum = `sum(row['speed_range_id']*row['count(speed_range_id)'] for row in speed_result)` line the [speed_range_id] row is still multiplying by the if and not by the assigned value.